# ASP.NET Identity vs Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-identity-3

I've been developing a Cordova app using Azure's Mobile App Service product.  It offers external sign-in through Facebook, but it doesn't offer a ready-made solution for storing the user into a SQL database where I can also add custom profile columns.

If I was making this app 5+ years ago, I would have used ASP.NET Identity to authenticate the web api, allow account creation with username/passwords as well as offering Facebook sign-in, and I'd be able to create custom profile items, all in a searchable database.

It's 2020 and I'm confused about what is the recommended modern method to achieve the same result.  I've read a lot about Azure AD B2C and it seems to tick all the boxes, but I'm worried it might not be as searchable as a SQL user store, and possibly appear to the user as a tacked-on product which isn't as native as the existing app.

I'd appreciate any advice or recommendations about which method I should use for creating my authenticated user store.

Comment: This may be helpful. Although it's about AD, it's talking about "claims" which as I understand it, is additional attributes attached to an identity. If you focus your searches on "claims" it might come up with something more helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995840/azure-mobile-app-service-cordova-with-c-sharp-backend-using-azure-ad-how-to

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom database, then set up an OAuth provider (e.g. [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Identity-Server#:~:text=Identity%20Server%201%20Introduction.%20Identity%20Server%20is%20an,now%20ready%20to%20get%20requests%20from%20clients.%20](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Identity-Server#:%7E:text=Identity%20Server%201%20Introduction.%20Identity%20Server%20is%20an,now%20ready%20to%20get%20requests%20from%20clients.%20)) and use that as the authentication scheme.  You can then use any OAuth client library to do the authentication, and set that up as a custom auth scheme in your Azure Mobile Apps service.